# Move mssql db Amazon RDS to EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

I have my 200 gb database.

I want to move EC2 from RDS.

I work on a research to prevent the problems that you may see,but it has not been done before.

**There may be problems;**

*Security weaknesses,

*High availability,

*Restore process takes a long time,

*In RDS, the time zone will be UTC, and UTC + 3 in EC2.

What other problems might occur from this problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step back a little: you're basically switching from a SQL Server that someone else manages, to managing your own server.

**Q: What are the security challenges involved with running your own server?**

You can get hacked, or you can incorrectly set permissions to let strangers access your data and publish it. Here are some resources to get you started:

- Microsoft's [SQL Server 2008 Compliance Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6808) white paper - it's very much still relevant today
- The book [Securing SQL Server](http://amzn.to/2lg9ANS) by Denny Cherry

**Q: What are the high availability challenges involved?**

Amazon RDS for SQL Server uses database mirroring for high availability. In your own EC2 instances, you can choose whether you'd like a similar level of protection with mirroring or Always On Availability Groups, or if you'd like to save money and get less protection.

You didn't ask about patching, but I'd bundle that in here: the burdens of patching will now be on you rather than Amazon.

**Q: Can I make my migration restores go faster?**

Right now, Amazon RDS only gives you access to full backups. Your backup/restore migration timeline is:

- Shut down your app
- Back up RDS to S3
- Restore the S3 file backup to EC2 SQL Server
- Start your app again

That's going to result in long downtimes for a 200GB database. To shorten it, you can use tools like Red Gate's Data Compare or build your own comparison tool to detect what changes have been made to your database. For example, on one project, the developers added LastUpdated timestamp fields to all the tables, and maintained those with triggers. Then, after our restore, we could shut down the apps, copy across the specific records that had been updated, and go live with only a few minutes of downtime.

**Q: What time zone should I use for my EC2 servers?**

Just as RDS was configured with UTC, so should your SQL Servers. Just set your EC2 boxes to be in UTC time zone regardless of their location, and then you won't have problems when you fail over from one region to another.

Comment: Hi Brent, thank you very much for your reply.
I will use your suggestions to solve my problems.
But the main responsibility was that, after the move,Is it possible to see new problems different than others?
If you have any prediction,can you tell me about it? I will try to take precautions

Comment: @Lyns sure, anytime you change SQL Servers, there are hundreds or thousands of problems you could see. That question is just too broad.

Comment: You're right. RDS has properties, ECT does not. All features can cause problems. Thank you.